# Specifying *stack-trace-depth* in Clojure tests

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

What is the correct way to set the value of `*stack-trace-depth*` in Clojure tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind it around your call to `run-tests` or `run-all-tests`.

For example:

```
(binding [*stack-trace-depth* 5] (run-all-tests))
```

Comment: Does this change the value of `*stack-trace-depth*` or simply hides it with this binding?

Comment: It's a dynamic, thread-local binding of a Var, which lasts as long as the `binding` scope.  The Var's "root value" remains unchanged.  See http://clojure.org/vars