# Modifying `cake test` to control stack trace depth (Clojure)

Tags: clojure

I'd like to modify `cake test` so that it operates with [a different value for `*stack-trace-depth*`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331541/specifying-stack-trace-depth-in-clojure-tests).

The [built-in definition](https://github.com/ninjudd/cake/blob/771f2572f24051ba7791998d1a47669f6141f231/src/cake/tasks/test.clj) is simply:

```
(deftask test #{compile}
  "Run project tests."
  "Specify which tests to run as arguments like: namespace, namespace/function, or :tag"
  (run-project-tests))
```

Ideally I'd like to specify the value with the command-line argument `--depth=n`, something to this effect:

```
(binding [*stack-trace-depth* (if (*opts* :depth)
                                  (read-string (*opts* :depth)))]
         (run-project-tests))
```

What code do I need to make this work?

---

Based on responses: Putting the following in `tasks.clj`

```
(undeftask test)
(deftask test #{compile}
  (.bindRoot #'*stack-trace-depth* 5)
  (println "Defining task: *stack-trace-depth* is" *stack-trace-depth* "in" (Thread/currentThread))
  (run-project-tests))
```

produces the following output:

> Loading `test/cake_test/core.clj`:
>
> ```
>   Loading tests: *stack-trace-depth* is nil in #<Thread[thread-13,5,main]>
> ```
>
> `$ cake test`
>
> ```
>   Defining task: *stack-trace-depth* is 5 in #<Thread[Thread-18,5,main]>
>   In test: *stack-trace-depth* is nil in #<Thread[Thread-16,5,main]>
>
>   Testing cake-testing.core
>
>   FAIL in (test-stack-trace-depth) (core.clj:8)
>   expected: (= *stack-trace-depth* 5)     
>   actual: (not (= nil 5))
>
>   Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
>   1 failures, 0 errors.
>   ----
>   Finished in 0.011865 seconds.
> ```

(Tested code is [on Gist](https://gist.github.com/d77cdcf74e023bc205e3/5391d2dfa976d3a844ef89259bca9932ebdf4e2d).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Update: threw out the original answer, here's what seems to be a working solution.)*

I took the sample project from your Gist and made the following changes:

1. `rm tasks.clj`
2. Added the following code to `project.clj` below the `defproject` form:

   ```
   (use '[bake.find-namespaces :only [find-namespaces-in-dir]]
        '[cake.tasks.test :only [test-opts]])


   (undeftask test)
   (deftask test #{compile}
     (bake (:use bake.test
                 [bake.core :only [with-context]]
                 [clojure.test :only [*stack-trace-depth*]])
       [namespaces (find-namespaces-in-dir (java.io.File. "test"))
        opts       (test-opts)]
       (with-context :test
         (binding [*stack-trace-depth* 5]
           (run-project-tests namespaces opts)))))
   ```
3. Created a new file, `test/cake_testing/core_test.clj` with the following contents:

   ```
   (ns cake-testing.core-test
     (:use clojure.test))


   (deftest correct-stack-trace-depth?
     (is (= *stack-trace-depth* 5)))
   ```

At this point, everything seems to work -- `cake test` outputs

```
Testing cake-testing.core-test

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
----
Finished in 0.033200374 seconds.
```

Also, adding in a "test" which deliberately throws an exception results in a nice, short stack trace being printed.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like the tests still aren't seeing the updated value. I've added some test output to the question.

Comment: The new version above (the result inlining a `*stack-trace-depth*`-setting version of `cake.tasks.test/run-project-tests` in a custom version of the `test` task) seems to work for me. Time now to dig into Cake to learn *why* it does, as I can't seem to grok the codebase yet. It looks pretty cool, though; thanks for getting me interested! :-)

Comment: I thought I hade it set up to where I would get notified of cake questions, guess I don't! :) Anyways, this is a great idea, would anyone be interested in submitting this as a patch to master?

Comment: @lancepantz: I'd be happy to provide a patch / pull request. I guess if this were to go inside the default `test` task, it ought to be possible to override the default -- say, with an extra switch in the `defproject` form? (`:test-stack-trace-depth` or sth?) The real solution would be either to make tasks (or at least some specific tasks like `test`) configurable to bind certain Vars to certain values or to make contexts (which I don't fully grok quite yet) capable of setting Vars. I think it'd be fun to do that, but I won't have that much time for leisurely coding until Friday at least.

Answer (score 2):

Was able to put this in a task.clj file at the same level as a project.clj file and when I run `cake test --depth=5` I can see the "Running tests with *stack-trace-depth* = 5" being printed. Hope this helps.

```
(ns tasks
  (:use cake cake.core cake.tasks.test
        [clojure.test :only [*stack-trace-depth*]]))

(undeftask test)
(deftask test #{compile}
  "Run tests"
  (binding [*stack-trace-depth* (if (*opts* :depth)
                                     (read-string (first (*opts* :depth))))]
    (println "Running tests with *stack-trace-depth* = " *stack-trace-depth*)
    (run-project-tests)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Unfortunately, when I run the tests they see the value of `clojure.test/*stack-trace-depth*` as `nil`, so there's something still missing. :/

Comment: Looks like you are right. I've poked around the cake source for a while now, looks like `run-project-tests` ends up creating a new context for running the users tests. I'm guessing you would need to be able to bind `*stack-trace-depth*` in that context. I played around with it some and wasn't able to come up with a good solution but I think it would be simple enough to add this functionality to cake. Good luck.